# Installing Mysql group replication plugin

Tags: 16.04, mysql

When I give 
 INSTALL PLUGIN group_replication SONAME 'group_replication.so';
command in mysql, I get the following error [image: error]
And when I navigate to the directory, there is no package named group_replication.so. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with mysql 5.7.21. How do I install the package from a source or is there any other way to overcome this issue and proceed with the replication?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue as well, explained in more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535713/mysql-group-replication-plugin-not-found-in-version-5-7-19-5-7-21.

What I learned what that not all versions of mysql come bundled with group replication. I instead had to install the "MySQL Community Version"

```
#[OPTIONAL] Completely remove current MySQL installation:
sudo service mysql stop
apt remove --purge mysql-\*
rm -rf /etc/mysql
rm -rf /var/log/mysql
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean

#Install MySQL Community Version 5.7.X:
sudo apt-get install libaio1
sudo apt-get install libmecab2
curl -OL https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/file/mysql-common_5.7.20-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb
curl -OL https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/file/mysql-community-client_5.7.20-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb
curl -OL https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/file/mysql-client_5.7.20-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb
curl -OL https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/file/mysql-community-server_5.7.20-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-common_5.7.20-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-community-client_5.7.20-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-client_5.7.20-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-community-server_5.7.20-1ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb
```

You should then find the plugin and be able to install it:

```
root@00.00.00.00:/var/log/mysql# ls -lah /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.7M Sep 13  2017 group_replication.so
....
```

Comment: Instead of manually downloading and installing the packages you might want to add the Oracle APT repo: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/